# Naming of a class which is receiving raw messages and calls known interface

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, message

How to name a class which is responsible for:

- receiving messages like `Receive(string address, byte[] body) { /*
  ... */}`, parse address, deserealize body, and call the right method
  of known interface tree with typed parameters (taken from
  deserialized body), for example `Open(int timeout)`
- react on events of known interface tree, like `event Action<string>
  OpeningError`, build the right address string, serialize parameters
  to `byte[]` and raise own `event Action<string, byte[]> NewMessage`

Comment: Bob. Definitely.

Comment: Maybe MessageService?

Comment: Dispatcher? Or even better, BobDispatcher.

Comment: @Robert Definitly SpongeBobDispatcher!

Comment: Dispatcher is probably best but you should include what kind of object is being dispatched if possible... i.e BobDispatcher dispatches Bob's

Comment: Now considering two variants: `Dispatcher` and `Router`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you design is close to the "Reactor pattern". But, generally speaking, if it is difficult to label, it could be an improvable or simplifiable idea. Take a look on "keep it simple principle"

Comment: About simplifying. I think there's no way to simplify the idea. Conditions are pretty simple: I receive message from network with string address and I need to route it to the right method. Of course, Each particular step can be delegated to a specialized class, for example, deserializing, and the system will remain simple, but it still needs a name. Reactor fits best

Comment: You can find the Reactor Pattern in POSA2